# Is there any library to format currency values in java?

Tags: java, format, currency

I have currency code and value in double. Need to do formating for Currencies.I tried with NumberFormat and Locale but in this case for example EURO has different Locale related to countries. How can I achieve this?, Is there any common format for Euro?

````
       format.setCurrency(Currency.getInstance("EUR"));
       format.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);
       
       System.out.println(format.format(dbl));

Locale[] locales = NumberFormat.getAvailableLocales();

       for(Locale lo : locales){
           NumberFormat format = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(lo);
           if(NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(lo).getCurrency().getCurrencyCode().equals("EUR")){
          
               System.out.println(    NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(lo).getCurrency().getCurrencyCode()+"-"+lo.getDisplayCountry() +"-"+NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(lo).getCurrency().getSymbol() +format.format(dbl));  

           }
       }```
````

Comment: You need to add some code you tried, but how about

Comment: String newStr = oldStr.replaceAll("[^\\d.]+", "")

Comment: Use the Java Money and Currency API to do this: http://javamoney.github.io/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been using [icu4j](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.ibm.icu/icu4j) library from a long time and it serves this purpose very well. It has many number formatters, including currency formatter. Please check below code:

```
final com.ibm.icu.text.NumberFormat rule = RuleBasedNumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(new Locale("en", "EU"));
System.out.println(rule.format(1054979.30));
```

It will print: `€1,054,979.30`

There are many configurations which will help you to tweak the output.

**EDIT:**

If you want to pass the currency code and format according to that, below is the code for it:

```
final com.ibm.icu.text.NumberFormat rule = RuleBasedNumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
rule.setCurrency(Currency.getInstance("EUR"));
System.out.println(rule.format(1054979.30));
```

Comment: whether this library supports currency code as input rather than locale

Comment: Yes. Check my edited answer.

Comment: Thanks for the update, is this library open source or licensed?
but generally values in euro specified in this format ("###.##0,00") right?

Comment: It is an open source. Here is the link to it - https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/informix-servers/12.10?topic=data-international-components-unicode-icu

Comment: So you mean to say that it should be dot (.) instead of comma (,) as a digit separator?

Comment: yes it should be (.)

Comment: I guess both dot and comma are interchangeable in Euro, and both are considered valid. Whereas comma makes amount more readable.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235918/discussion-between-dak-and-jignesh-m-khatri).

Answer (score 1):

Before you go and check different formats of displaying EURO values, let Java do the conversion for you.

Use the `java.text.NumberFormat` class this way:

```java
NumberFormat currFormatter = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.GERMANY);
double money = 2000000;
System.out.println(currFormatter .format(money));
```

The above codes outputs:

```
2.000.000,00 €
```

Choose the `Locale` as to your need.

Comment: @user16320675 when I answered, there was no code at all in the question. So I supposed the OP didn't know anything about `NumberFormat`